# Redirect Everything except home page and css folder & image folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

I need htaccess code that can redirect my entire olddomain.com to a newdomain.com without redirecting the images folder, css folder and js folder, and without redirecting the home page of olddomain.com[will act as my Landing page]
Tried this code but didn't work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js(/|$)
RewriteRule ^$ https://newdomain.com [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ℅{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
#exclude /images folder
RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/ [NC]
#exculde /css folder
RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/ [NC]
#exclude /js folder
RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/ [NC]
#exclude old domain homepage
RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
#redirect everything else to new domain
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

To redirect requests from your old domain to the new domain homepage , just replace the rule (the last line) with this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/ [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: That seems not to work. Is it because my domains are https and also non www? or that does not matter

Comment: This should  work  on https and non www domain  as well. Can you please be more specific about the issue you are having?  What url are you going to and what is currently  happening?